# How can I change Linux terminal to make it look like the command "top"?

Tags: linux, system-calls

My aim is to make a program using C or C++ that prints to the Linux console in a similar way "top" does, in the sense that top's content updates and changes the existing text in the console, rather than printing new lines. How? I only want to know what are the syscalls or functions that make this possible. A little example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a fair question, but asking for software library recommendations are off-topic on this site because answers tend to be opinion-based and prone to flame-wars.

Comment: I didn't ask for wars. My question is not ambiguous. Only how to do what I asked.